# find all odd permutations $\sigma \in S_4$ such that $\sigma (123) \sigma^{-1} = (234) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

need help with this question...

> find all odd permutations $\sigma \in S_4$  such that 
>   $\sigma (123) \sigma^{-1} = (234) $

really have no idea how to approach this.
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\sigma(a_1~a_2~\cdots~a_k)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(a_1)~\sigma (a_2)~\cdots~\sigma (a_k))$.

Comment: I pretty much need further explanation.

Comment: @Tal according to the given upvotes, you'd rather get the whole answer developed for you instead of receiving only some hints and *then* doing some self work. Why don't you try to prove the nice hint this answer gives you instead?

Comment: @Tal Can you prove the claim in my hint? Using my hint, what can we say about a $\sigma\in S_4$ given that $\sigma(123)\sigma^{-1}=(234)$? I can split that question up into two parts: what does the left-hand side of the equation become, and what does the equality of cycles $(abc)=(xyz)$ imply for the things $a,b,c,x,y,z$?

Answer (score 3):

There are three permutations $\sigma\in S^4$ such that $\sigma\,(1\,2\,3)\,\sigma^{-1}=(2\,3\,4)$:
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 1\end{array}\right),\qquad \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 & 1\end{array}\right),\qquad \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 2 & 3 & 1\end{array}\right)$$
or, in cycle notation:
$$ (1\,2\,3\,4),\qquad (1\,3\,2\,4),\qquad (1\,4). $$
They are odd permutations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the cycle thingy and what the other answer shows. For example:

$$\sigma_1:\begin{cases}1\mapsto2\\2\mapsto3\\3\mapsto4\end{cases}\implies \sigma_1=(1234)$$

**or**

$$\sigma_2:\begin{cases}1\mapsto3\\2\mapsto4\\3\mapsto2\end{cases}\implies \sigma_2=(1324)$$

and etc.